# How expensive are multiple requires on the same file on the same instance of Node JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins

My understanding of require (so far) is that it performs a traversal up the directory structure, looking for the module you're trying to import. Well, [that's not exactly correct](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm), but let's assume the directory traversal cost is negligible.

I have a module called `BigModule`. It has a lot of stuff in it, so there's some cost associated with loading it up with a `require` statement. Is importing it a hundred times a hundred times more expensive than importing it once, or is there some sort of caching mechanism which causes these scripts to share one `BigModule` instance? This is all happening on a single Node instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require()` caches calls by resolved filepath; `require()`ing the same file twice (even via symlink or different relative path) will not rerun the code.